# In p5, use mouseClicked() function only when the canvas is clicked

Tags: p5.js, mouseclick-event

In p5 I have a code with `mouseClicked()` function.
I want this function to be called **only when the canvas is clicked**.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer. When creating the canvas, link it to a function like this:

```js
function setup() {
    var canvas = createCanvas(width, height);
    canvas.mouseClicked(my_function);
    ...
}

function my_function(){
...
}
```